# Building and distributing python moduel using rpm

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, rpm, distutils

I am trying to build and distribute rpm package of python module for centos. I have followed following steps

1. created virtualenv and installed requires
2. in module added setup.py with install_requires.
3. then using python2.7 from virtualenv build package

   ../env/bin/python2.7 setup.py bdist_rpm
4. Now I got src, no-arch and tar-gz files in 'dist' folder.
   foo-0.1-1.noarch.rpm,  foo-0.1-1.src.rpm,  foo-0.1.tar.gz

I tried to install package src-rpm using '`sudo yum install foo-0.1-1.src.rpm`', 
got error something like wrong architecture

Then I tried to install package no-arch, '`sudo yum install foo-0.1-1.noarch.rpm`'  it works smoothly. 
But after running script, it gave some import error. here I expect to download that module automatically.

The last thing is I am using some third party library which is not on pip. 
**So I want to whole setup using virtualenv with required modules. So after installing rpm, user can run script directly instead of installing third party libs separately and explicitly.**

Some above steps may sounds wrong, as I am new to this stuff.

Following is code in setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "foo",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
    scripts = ['foo/bar.py', ],

    # Project uses reStructuredText, so ensure that the docutils get
    # installed or upgraded on the target machine
    install_requires = ['PyYAML', 'pyOpenSSL', 'pycrypto', 'privatelib1,'privatelib2', 'zope.interface'],

    package_data = {
        # If any package contains *.txt or *.rst files, include them:
        '': ['*.txt', '*.rst'],
        # And include any *.msg files found in the 'billing' package, too:
        'foo': ['*.msg'],
    },

    # metadata for upload to PyPI
    author = "foo bar",
    description = "foo bar",
    license = "",
    keywords = "foo bar",

    # could also include long_description, download_url, classifiers, etc.
)
```

Also I am using shebang in script as,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Note:
I have multiple python setups. 2.6 and 2.7 
By default 'python' commands gives 2.6 
while command 'python2.7' gives python2.7

output of `'rpm -qp foo-0.1-1.noarch.rpm --requires' =>

```
`/usr/bin/python  
python(abi) = 2.6
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
```

When i install pakcage. script's shebang line (which is now '/usr/bin/bar.py') is getting changed to `/usr/bin/python'` But I exclusively want to run  script on python2.7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably just a typo in the post here but you are missing a quote in ` 'privatelib1,'privatelib2'` after `privatelib1`. What script shebang line is changing? rpm shouldn't be modifying your files on you I don't think. That being said I don't think rpm is going to pick up non-standard python as the required `python(abi)` version either.